# Errors Adding Registrant

Tags: civievent

Recently created an event and started adding registrants. When I add a new registrant these errors appear:

Notice: Undefined index: is_show_location in CRM_Event_Form_Participant->postProcess() (line 1516 of /home/*****/www/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Event/Form/Participant.php).
Notice: Undefined index: metric in CRM_Core_BAO_PdfFormat::retrieve() (line 309 of /home/*****/www/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/BAO/PdfFormat.php).
Notice: Undefined index: metric in CRM_Core_BAO_PdfFormat::retrieve() (line 309 of /home/*****/www/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/BAO/PdfFormat.php).

I recently updated to 4.6.3 but it all seems to be working otherwise. Suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Did you back up your database before the update (as suggested) - can you find 'name' = 'metric' in your civicrm_option_value table?

Comment: I did back it up. And I will check that table.

Comment: No, there is no Metric record.

Comment: So can I assume this field should =have been added?  Is there some reason the upgrade script would not have updated  the database?

Comment: I'm sorry that should be 'value'  in civicrm_option_value (ie, select value from civicrm_option_value where value like "%metric%"), there are a number of those for sizing the Pdf report - but your trace also says the field 'is_show_location' is undefined @ line 1516 in Participant.php.  It doesn't make sense offhand as 'is_show_location'  which is a FK to location for the show.  In your 4.6.3 database, your civicrm_event table should have a field 'is_show_location', is that defined?  I would imagine it is - it's referenced in 4.6.4

Comment: And now there's another version released! So do I stay put and fix? Or upgrade and hope it fixes it?

Comment: Yes, there 24 entries similar to: {"metric":"in","width":7.25,"height":10.5}

Comment: And the ';is_show-location' is NULL.